# Socket can be send only once and the Textview is not gathering the information from the server

Tags: java, android, sockets, interface, udp

I had two issues in the program I am making... the thing is that I want to send by a Edittext that information to a server via UDP....the thing is that the program only works the first time I run the program, I mean, if i open the application and write some text, the information is sended to the server, but if I type another thing and press to button so the new information is sended it doesn't work... the other thing is that the TextView is not appending the information, and the server send some info but the application is not gathering that information... so if someone had a clue why is this happening or what I am doing wrong I appreciated any help!... Thanks in advice...

here is the code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
public static final String SERVERIP = "190.99.20.200";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 5153;
public TextView serverResponse;
public EditText messageToSend;
public Button btnSend;
public boolean start;
public Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    serverResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    messageToSend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    start = false;
    new Thread(new Server()).start();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        updatetrack("Error on Server:" + e.getMessage());
    }
    new Thread(new Client()).start();
    handler = new Handler(){
        public void handledMessage(Message msg){
            String text = (String)msg.obj;
            serverResponse.append(text);
        }
    };
}

public class Client implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(start == false)
        {
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch (InterruptedException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            InetAddress serverAddres = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            updatetrack("Client:Start connectingn");
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] buffer;
            if(!messageToSend.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            {
                buffer = messageToSend.getText().toString().getBytes();
            }
            else
            {
                buffer = ("Message from android").getBytes();
            }
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,serverAddres,SERVERPORT);
            updatetrack("Client:Sending" + new String(buffer)+ "'n");
            socket.send(packet);
            updatetrack("Client: Messange sentn");
            updatetrack("Client: Succed!n ");
            socket.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            updatetrack("Client:Error!n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class Server implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (start == false)
        {
        }
        try{
            InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            updatetrack("nServer: Start connectingn");
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT, serverAddress);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[17];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            updatetrack("Server: Receivingn");
            socket.receive(packet);
            updatetrack("Server: Message received:" + new String(packet.getData())+"'n");
            updatetrack("Server : Succed!n");

        }catch (Exception e){
            updatetrack("Server: Error!n"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    start = true;
}

public void updatetrack(String s)
{
    Message msg = new Message();
    String textTochange = s;
    msg.obj = textTochange;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need to call `toString()` on a `String` as returned by `getText().`

Comment: @EJP thanks for the reply, hows that? so what type could it be?

Answer (score 1):

The `run` method in your server class will run only once.

```
while(start == false){
}
```

This while loop will continue to loop until you call the `onClick` method, at which point the rest of the code in the `run()` method is executed, and the server thread killed. You need to rearrange your code a little, and place it inside the `while` loop:

```
public void run() {
    while (true){

    try{
        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        updatetrack("nServer: Start connectingn");
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT, serverAddress);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[17];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        updatetrack("Server: Receivingn");
        socket.receive(packet);
        updatetrack("Server: Message received:" + new String(packet.getData())+"'n");
        updatetrack("Server : Succed!n");

    }catch (Exception e){
        updatetrack("Server: Error!n"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: HI @Daniel Mac, thanks for the reply and sorry for the late, I do the change but when I Initialice the application i throws nullpointer exception from updateTrack, I thinks is maybe because server do not reply unless information is sended... thanks in advice